# How to keep my Python script running infinitely (loop)?

Tags: python, loops, telegram

I am building a Telegram bot that tells me the price of Bitcoin in USD whenever I send the bot a "/price" command on Telegram. It works, however the price does not update unless I re-run the Python script.
How can I keep the script running forever so that I do not need to constantly click "run"?
Here is my code:

```
import requests
import telebot


# BITCOIN DATA
url = 'https://api.coinbase.com/v2/prices/USD/spot?'
response = requests.get(url).json()



# BOT STUFF
bot = telebot.TeleBot("1135809125:AAHHx7sZ5276Kg34VWYDuwHIJB76s5QS9UQ")


@bot.message_handler(commands=['price'])
def send_welcome(message):
    bot.reply_to(message, "The current price of Bitcoin in USD is " + response['data'][0]['amount'])


@bot.message_handler(func=lambda message: True)
def echo_all(message):
    bot.reply_to(message, message.text)


bot.polling()
```

Comment: It's called a loop, and is covered in many existing tutorials.  As such, the question is out of scope for Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe try with `itertools`:

```
import itertools
for x in itertools.repeat(1):
    bot.polling()
```

Or `itertools.count()`:

```
import itertools
for elt in itertools.count():
    bot.polling()
```

Or according to [link](https://github.com/eternnoir/pyTelegramBotAPI/issues/98), you can try this:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
     bot.polling(none_stop=True)
```

Comment: The last edit still does not work :( I really appreciate it though

Answer (score 1):

response should be inside `send_welcome` to get the current price everytime you send a /price command.

```py
    @bot.message_handler(commands=['price'])
    def send_welcome(message):
        response = requests.get(url).json()
        bot.reply_to(message, "The current price of Bitcoin in USD is " + response['data'][0]['amount'])
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a `while` loop:

```
import requests
import telebot

# BITCOIN DATA
url = 'https://api.coinbase.com/v2/prices/USD/spot?'
response = requests.get(url).json()



# BOT STUFF
bot = telebot.TeleBot("1135809125:AAHHx7sZ5276Kg34VWYDuwHIJB76s5QS9UQ")


@bot.message_handler(commands=['price'])
def send_welcome(message):
    bot.reply_to(message, "The current price of Bitcoin in USD is " + response['data'][0]['amount'])


@bot.message_handler(func=lambda message: True)
def echo_all(message):
    bot.reply_to(message, message.text)

while True:

    bot.polling()
```